# How do you register a custom helper if you are precompiling a custom helper in Handlebars.js?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to precompile a Handlebars.js template `app/views/templates/walrus.handlebar` with the command `handlebar app/views/templates/walrus.handlebar` but it fails because the template uses a custom helper that I have defined in a seperate js file `public/javascripts/handlebar_helpers.js`.

How do I call the command line version of Handlebars so it is aware of the javascript file with the custom helper?

Comment: Did you ever find how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
handlebars <input> -f <output> -k <helper>
```

It's in the docs here: http://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html

Edit March 2014:

For people having issues reading the docs, here's an example for custom helper "fullname"

```
handlebars myTemplate.handlebars -f handlebars-fullname.js -k fullname
```

with this helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('fullname', function(person) {
  return person.firstName + " " + person.lastName;
});
```

You still have to include the helper in the page with the `handlebars.runtime.js`

Comment: @wusher What did your call look like? I'm not sure how -k is used with custom helpers.

Comment: I'm looking for the answer to this. `-k` only works for native helpers, not custom...

Comment: @all See additional example. It works and has done so for years at this point.

Comment: note for AMD support, you may also have to add `Handlebars = Handlebars["default"];` prior to your `Handlebars.registerHelper` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
handlebars myTemplate.handlebars -f handlebars-fullname.js -k fullname
```

**The above step is not a mandatory one**, your handlebar template would work even if you dont specify the helper name during pre-compilation, however the following code (which basically should contain all of your helpers) needs to be inserted on the client-side

```
    Handlebars.registerHelper('fullname', function(person) {
  return person.firstName + " " + person.lastName;
});
```

I have tried this and it works like a charm!